# Find count of rows with empty value in Hbase

Tags: hadoop, count, hbase, bigdata, apache-zookeeper

I have populated a Hbase table with rowid and vrious information pertaining to tweet such as clean-text,url,hashtag etc. as follows

```
902221655086211073    column=clean-tweet:clean-text-cta, timestamp=1514793745304, value=democrat mayor order hurricane harvey stand houston
```

However while populating I noticed that the some of the rows are empty like

```
902487280543305728    column=clean-tweet:clean-text-cta, timestamp=1514622371008, value=
```

Now how do I find the count of rows that are having data?

Please help me in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no provision to do this in HBase shell as of now. May be you can use a simple code like this to get a number of records with no value for the provided column qualifier.

CountAndFilter [tableName] [columnFamily] [columnQualifier]

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Admin;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Connection;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultScanner;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Table;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

public class CountAndFilter {

private static Connection conn;
private static int recordsWithoutValue = 0;
public static Admin getConnection() throws IOException {
    if (conn == null) {
        conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(HBaseConfiguration.create());
    }
    return conn.getAdmin();
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    getConnection();
    scan(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
    System.out.println("Records with empty value : " + recordsWithoutValue);
}

public static void scan(String tableName, String columnFamily, String columnQualifier) throws IOException {
    Table table = conn.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tableName));
    ResultScanner rs = table.getScanner(new Scan().addColumn(Bytes.toBytes(columnFamily), Bytes.toBytes(columnQualifier)));

    Result res = null;
    try {
        while ((res = rs.next()) != null) {
            if (res.containsEmptyColumn(Bytes.toBytes(columnFamily), Bytes.toBytes(columnQualifier))){
                recordsWithoutValue++;
            }
        }
    } finally {
        rs.close();
    }
}
}
```